# XSLT grouping of nodes between two nodes using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have quer could you please let me know hour to group below nodes using XSLT, from the  input which i gave below

```
Once I get into above structure I have written temple which will extract and keep into my companies format of XML. 
<X12Transaction>(Root)
<ISA> 
<GS>
<ST>
<BHT>
<HL> </HL>------1
<NM1> </NM1>
<PER> </Per>
<HL> </HL>----------------2
<NM1> </NM1>
.......
.......
.....

<HL> </HL>------------3
REF>
<N3>
<N4>
<EB>
<EB>
<DTP>
<LS>
<NM1>
<NM3>
< LE>

<HL> </HL>------------4
REF>
<N3>
<N4>
<EB>
<EB>
<DTP>

<SE>
<GE>
<IEA>

</X12Transaction>(Root)
```

I am new to XSLT please provide your suggestions

1) first HL to second HL into source 
2) Second Hl to third HL into payer
3) Thrid HL to fourth HL into subscriber and 
       a)if EB node exist if it is followed by DTP then move DTP node as a child of EB node
        b) Extract nodes from LS to LE put into child nodes
4) Fourth HL to till SE put into Dependent 
     do the same as above 3) rules a) and b)

Comment: A valid XML example of input and the expected output would be useful.

Answer (score -2):

See if this can get you started:

```
...
<source>
    <xsl:for-each select="X12Transaction/*[count(preceding-sibling::HL) = 1 and not (self::HL)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</source>
...
```

Comment: Seriously disturbed people vote me down - but this is good code nevertheless.